# Kestrel .NET API - Cannot connect with mongodb// url

Tags: .net, mongodb, azure, service, kestrel

I have configurated my .net core API connected to a Mongo DB. I have connected to it from a ConnectionString something as "mongodb//user:password@server ...". At the moment, in local the connection is fine, I can connect with MongoDB. The problem is when I publish it, the server log streams show me something related with Kestrel proxy, and cannot resolve "mongodb://". In fact, mongodb string appears like unknown.

I have configurated the connection in a app.settings.json file:

"ConnectionStrings": {
    "db": "mongodb://admin:blbablabla@url:27017/?authSource=admin"

```
    var uri = new MongoUr(_configuration.GetSection(CONNECTIONSTRINGS)[db];
    _mongoDBClient = new MongoClient(uri);
```

That is the error:

```
2019-01-25 13:10:42.366 +00:00 [Error] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel: Connection id "0HLK2OOVSKRD5", Request id "0HLK2OOVSKRD5:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
    System.TimeoutException: A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a 
server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = 
MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, 
LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. 
Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : " 
Automatic", Type : "Unknown", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: 
"{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/urlmachine:27017" }", EndPoint: 
"Unspecified/urlmachine:27017", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", 
HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception 
occurred while opening a connection to the server. ---> 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such host is known
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(Exception source)
       at System.Net.Dns.HostResolutionEndHelper(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Net.Dns.EndGetHostAddresses(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Net.Dns.<>c.<GetHostAddressesAsync>b__25_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

Comment: The exception states that the endpoint you are trying to connect to is `Unspecified/urlmachine:27017`, are you sure that the uri is what you think it is?

Comment: Yes, in localhost It works fine

Comment: Does it work with the url `Unspecified/urlmachine:27017`? I think you don't have the correct JSON config on the remote server

Comment: No sorry I didn't explain well. In local, the mongo:// url is resolved as well. But when I deploy to azure app services, the connection string is resolved as unspecified

Comment: I have solved the problem. The error was caused because the app were not able to connect to MongoDB. MongoDB DB is located in a network doesn't accessible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. The error was caused because the app were not able to connect to MongoDB. MongoDB DB is located in a network doesn't accessible